# Update webform field value using AJAX realtime

Tags: hooks, ajax, webforms, forms

I have a webform created using the admin panel and would like to change one of its textfield values on click of a button. I have attempted doing this from hook_form_alter. I have given the wrapper name 'changeText' for this textfield from admin panel.

```
function fence_quote_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_1'){
        $form['buttons']['fence_quote']  = array(
          '#type' => 'button',
          '#value' => t('Get online estimates'),
          '#ajax' => array(
              'callback' => 'fence_quote_form_callback', 
              'wrapper' => 'changeText',
          ),
        );
       $form['field_meters']['#prefix'] = '<div id="changeText">';
       $form['field_meters']['#sufix'] = '</div>';
    }   
}

function fence_quote_form_callback($form, &$form_state) {
   $form_state['values']['field_meters']['und'][0]['value'] = '111';
   return $form['wrapper'];
}
```

The problem is I can't update 'meters' value using AJAX callback as it is a field created from admin panel and not from hook_form_alter. However if I place

```
$form['submitted']['meters']['#default_value'] = '111';
```

outside of the callback it works on page refresh. How can I do this?

---

As requested by @kamal-oberoi I'm uploading a screenshot of my full code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured this out!

```
$form['submitted']['total']['#prefix'] = '<div id="changeText">';
$form['submitted']['total']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

$form['buttons']['fence_quote']  = array(
            '#type' => 'button',
            '#value' => t('Get online estimates'),
            '#ajax' => array(
              'callback' => 'fence_quote_form_callback', 
              'wrapper' => 'changeText', 
            ),
);
```

Then inside callback function

```
$form['submitted']['total']['#value'] = '111';
return $form['submitted']['total'];
```

Answer (score 1):

add wrapper to your text field which you want to update.

```
 function fence_quote_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_1'){
    $form['buttons']['fence_quote']  = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Get online estimates'),
      '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'fence_quote_form_callback', 
          'wrapper' => 'changeText',
      ),
    );
    /* Please add Wrapper to text_field */
    $form['wrapper']['your_textfield_name']['#prefix'] = '<div id="changeText">';
    $form['wrapper']['your_textfield_name']['#sufix'] = '</div>';
  }  

}


function fence_quote_form_callback($form, &$form_state) {
     $form_state['values']['meters']['und'][0]['value'] = '111';
     return $form['wrapper'];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kamal-oberoi but I'm unable to identify name of my field to add wrapper. The field key of it is 'meters' but when I type $form['meters']['#prefix'] = '<div id="newtext">' it doesn't recognise.

Comment: Also there's an error message saying 'Undefined index: wrapper in fence_quote_form_callback()'

Comment: I managed to identify the name of field. It's $form['submitted']['meters']['#prefix']. However I still get the error 'Undefined index: wrapper in fence_quote_form_callback()'. Seems like wrapper can't be returned that way.

Comment: Please change this $form['submitted']['meters']['#prefix'] to $form_state['values']['field_meters']['und'][0]['value']

Comment: Still no luck.. throws this error message 'Undefined index: values in fence_quote_form_alter() '

Comment: please add the screen shot of your full code then i will check it..

Comment: Just updated question with full code

Comment: I pasted your updated code and still getting the error - 'Undefined index: wrapper in fence_quote_form_callback()'