# Where to put #Ajax Callback in webform twig file

Tags: 8, webforms

I would like to add the Ajax callback settings to my custom composite webform element in the twig file.  Is this possible?  The callback function is in my custom module.  This is NOT a computed twig situation.  The Webform is created entirely from D8 webform GUI.

Custom composite has qty, code, description, price.  Using the callback to verify code and update the description and price.
Could something like below be put in the twig file?

```
'#ajax' => (
    'callback' => 'validate_srvform_items',
    'event' => 'change',
    'progress' => array(
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => t('Populating line item...'),
    )
```

Comment: The `'#ajax'` should added in your `.module` file not  in the twig file, for example in `hook_form_alter` something like `$form['some_field']['#ajax'] = [
'callback' => 'validate_srvform_items',
    'event' => 'change',
    'progress' => [
    'type' => 'throbber',
    'message' => t('Populating line item...'),
    ]
]`
take a look https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms#s-adding-the-ajax-event

Comment: That link is very helpful, I never ran across it in my searches. Super.

Comment: Cool I'm glad that helped (y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a form alter function in your module file and then add the callback property to the respective field

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = [
  'callback' => 'callback',
  'event' => 'click',
];
```

See also

- [Alter Ajax callback on Webforms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264307/alter-ajax-callback-on-webforms)
- [How do I add an AJAX action on a select element in a ContentEntityForm to change the value of another select element](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/287969/how-do-i-add-an-ajax-action-on-a-select-element-in-a-contententityform-to-change/288063#288063)
- [Update webform field value using AJAX realtime](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/180047/update-webform-field-value-using-ajax-realtime)